# ngx-treeview height should be same size as the browser and dynamic with browser size

Tags: angular, ngx-treeview

config = TreeviewConfig.create({
hasAllCheckBox: false,
hasFilter: true,
hasCollapseExpand: false,
decoupleChildFromParent: false,
maxHeight: 600
});

**i am trying to make responsive ngx-treeview and its height should show as browser size only. if items are more than browser then automatically scroll i m getting on this treeview but problem is as i set 'maxHeight : 600' then it is larger height than my browser screen but if i don't set maxHeight then it is 70% showing treeview on my screen. but i want dianamic treeview height which adjust with browser size automatically please help  **

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no official attribute available to set change the max-height to take full viewport height, you could try the CSS workaround.

Set this style to the 'styles.scss' (Global Stylesheet)

```
.treeview-container {
   max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```